# how to convert png to bmp for using dynamic navision?

Tags: c#, imagemagick, navision

I want to upload the bmp image in Dynamic Navision 2009 classic . I have png format images and need to convert as bmp. conversion of image is working only if i use MS paint/Photoshop tools. Same way i want convert the png image using Image magic or .Net code.

Alreadey tried using imagemagic tool code 
         Convert 1.png -background white -alpha remove 1.bmp
Image magic is converting the png to bmp but navision is not showing the image. Its only accepting if its converted by MS paint / Photoshop

Comment: Try `convert 1.png -background white -alpha remove -flatten 1.bmp`. Failing that, there are several BMP formats - you can list formats supported by Imagemagick with `identify -list formats`. You can try different formats by prefixing the output file name with `BMP2:` etc. - like this `convert 1.png -background white -alpha remove -flatten BMP2:1.bmp`.

Comment: And if you want to do what Jon mentions in .NET you should take a look at my project: https://magick.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use gimp for that. It shows all kind of options for saving/converting bitmaps and other formats (if you ever need them). Might be the easiest way instead of messing around with too much stuff. Make sure it has no alpha channel.